# How to multiply by a percentage range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula that will multiply a value by a percentage range, yielding a value range as the answer.

E.g.
=10*(10 to 12%)  -> 1 to 1.2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following would yield an array from 1-1.2 (when using ExcelO365)

```
=10*(SEQUENCE(3,,10)/100)
```

In essence we are creating `=10*{0.1,0.11,0.12}` without having to type this out ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I'm not sure where your inputs are, but one option (assuming upper, lower, and multiplier are all in separate cells) is to simply multiply as normal and concatenate the results.

If multiplier is in A1, lower is in A2, and upper is in A3 then this formula will work:

`=A1*A2&" to "&A1*A3`

That should return "1 to 1.2" using the example data provided.

Comment: You can also use the TEXT() function to format the cells, if you're multiplying numbers with long trailing decimals I would recommend using this formula:

`=TEXT(A1*A2,"0.0#")&" to "&TEXT(A1*A3,"0.0#")`

Which limits the response to two decimal places.